# What are the different types of birth?

Tags: scripture, birth

So in scriptures I have come across several types of birth that we would term extra ordinary. Few examples that come to my mind are

- Kunti giving birth via vidhi obtained from Sage Durvasa
- Kauravas being born outside womb
- Draupadi and Dhrishtadyumna coming out of a yagna

Is there a comprehensive description or enumeration of the various types of births possible as per scriptues ? Please note I am not looking for yagnas that ensure birth i.e. Ashwamedha, Putrakameshti etc or vratas . Only the types of birth

Edit 1
Looking for human births only; not animals, plants etc

Comment: For mortal beings, there are 4 - Pindaja (Womb), Andaja (Egg), Svedaja (Sweat), Udbeeja (Seed). For amara (aka devas), there is no human/mortal restrictions to avatara.

Comment: @ram - I assume you mean human when you say mortal beings. Can you put the same in an answer with a reference?

Comment: Aren't they only Yonija and Ayonija?..ur 1st instance is on how she conceive but birth was Yonija...3rd is Ayonija...2nd is Yonija but after 2yrs pregnancy instead of children a flesh came out and Vyasa divided it into 101 and did further processing..this is some how same for jarasandha who was born in 2 parts and Jara joined them..

Comment: @YDS - but do scriptures categorise even extra ordinary vaginal birth as yonija?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in one comment under the question the 4 types of yoni/birth mentioned in various Hindu scriptures are --- Udbhija, Andaja, Swedaja and Jarayuja.

I have read about these types of birth in Tantras as well as in Puranas.

Quoting from the book ["Essence of Padma Purana"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/padmapurana19.html):

> In this connection, Matali explained how different types of birth are
> envisaged and what kinds of difficulties were encountered from birth
> through one’s life till the end and so on. Depending on the ‘Karma’ of
> a ‘Praani’, births are decided as
>
> **‘Udbhija’ (sprouted from Earth like grass, vegetables etc.),
> ‘Swedaja’  (Krumi, Keeta and Flies), ‘Andaja’ (Birds, Fish etc. born
> out of eggs) and ‘Jarayuja’ (Animals, human beings etc. born out of
> physical  bodies)**
>
> . As a result of interaction of Pancha Bhutas viz. Earth, Fire, Water,
> Wind and Sky, ‘Anna’ or food gets materialised as six varieties viz.
> Bhakshya, Bhojya, Peya, lehya, Choshya and Khadya. Anna has twelve end
> results viz. Paaka( the cooked), Rasa (liquids), Mala or body reject,
> Rakta or blood, Roma (body hairs), ‘Maamsa’ or meat, kesha or head
> hairs, Snaayu or sinews, Mazza (marrow), haddi or bones, ‘Vasa’ and
> ‘Veerya’(sperm).

Quoting from Devi Bhagavatam, 13th Chapter of the 3rd Adhyaya (states the same thing which is mentioned in Padma Purana):

> 24. O King! Thus the three varieties, human beings, Devas, and Tiryakas (birds, etc.) and their great subvarieties sprang up.
> 25. **The four classes of Jîvas, Andaja (born from the eggs), Svedaja (born out of sweats), Udbhija (plants, etc.) and Jarâyujâ (men,
>     etc.)** were created, being endowed with the fruits of their past
>     auspicious or inauspicious Karmas, as the case may be

Now, the kind of classification of different types of birth, you are looking for, I don't think you will get some from scriptures. Of course, I can very well be wrong on this, since Hindu scriptures is such a vast subject but that's my opinion since I have not encountered something similar so far.

The only various types of birth mentioned in the scriptures are the ones I mentioned in this answer.

Comment: I think OP is specifically asking for human births type.

Comment: Human birth comes under Jarayuja (vaginal) and these are all the types of birth afaik. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: Thanks Rickross. But I think Kauravas and Draupadi were not vaginal births and considered humans. Pandavas and Karna were vaginal birth but not after usual 9, months gestation ( adi parva). How would we term these births ?

Comment: AFAIK these are only the various types of births given in scriptures. I don't think you will a get a classification like the one you're looking for @Carmensandiego

Comment: Can you add a line in the answer stating that you have not come across such classification ? That will then address the question , and I will accept it.

Comment: @Carmensandiego I have edited like the way you have suggested